# How to create a back button with a large left-facing arrow like the iPod app

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, ipod

How do I create a back button with a large left-facing arrow like in the iPod app? I'm not asking how to create a left-facing button, but how to get a left-facing arrow as the label on a button, as seen in the iPod app's now playing screen:

[image: iPod now playing screen]

Obviously an image would do the trick, but perhaps there is a Unicode character that they used? Also, I'm surprised that there's no discussion about this (or at least none that I could find).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it. You create the image and set it as the back button. The code below is what I have in my application.

```
UIImage *imageFullscreen = [UIImage imageNamed: @"fullscreen.png"];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imageFullscreen style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(hide)]autorelease]];
```

Comment: That was just my code you will have to adapt it a little to fit your needs.